# What are the difference between Java 1.4 Strings And Java 1.5 String And Java 1.6 Strings And Java 1.7 Strings.

Tags: string, class

I want to know the difference between the Java 1.4 to Java 1.7 (Only Strings) String class Enhancements

Comment: Please if anybody knows this ans can you please share with me.

Comment: Why don't you compare the Java Docs for each version?

Answer (score 0):

Java 5 - StringBuilder class (in java.lang package)

refer these links (http://xahlee.info/java8_doc/technotes/guides/lang/enhancements.html)

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/enhancements.html)
 for more.